# Missing high rep users by last post date

Tags: support, data-explorer

This stems from a chat:

> We lost indeed quite a few high reputation people over the last year. Seven in total by the count of this query: https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/1381723/which-high-reputation-users-have-we-lost

The query checks last visit. I tried to fork it and check last Q and/or A date, but there doesn't seem to be a label for that.

I'm in no way an SQL expert, and was wondering if a query can be made that checks that.

Comment: "Missing" and "lost" are misleading titles.... I might not visit or post on SO for months, and still come back to visit or even post. I'm not gone for good.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating: I agree. I've been away for close to a year for a myriad of reasons. If there's a better description, feel free to edit it in :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've [forked that query](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/1381934/which-high-reputation-users-have-we-lost?Reputation=10000&daysNotVisited=90) and added an inner join with the posts table so I could select the max creationdate of the posts.

```
select u.Id as [User Link]
    , u.Reputation
    , u.lastAccessDate 
    , max(ph.creationdate) [last post] 
from Users u 
inner join posts ph on ph.owneruserid = u.id
where Reputation >= ##Reputation:int?10000## 
group by u.Id , u.Reputation, u.lastAccessDate 
having max(ph.CreationDate) < (GetDate() - ##daysNotVisited:int?90##) 
order by max(ph.creationdate) desc
```